# Extract substrings from a given string in C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, extract

I have a string from which i want to extract a required string as :

```
"S101 Peter"
"S3282 Steve"
```

How to extract only the Names i.e. **Peter** and **Steve** from the above two strings. I worked out with Replace, Remove, TrimStart, IndexOf but couldn't find out? Please help...

Comment: If this helped you should consider marking it as answered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want [SubString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

```
var name = theString.SubString(theString.IndexOf(' ') + 1);
```

Comment: +1 for more efficient than string.Split and safe against a missing space.

Answer (score 5):

```
String S = "S101 Peter";
String S1 = S.split(" ")[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can ensure the pattern of "XXXX YYYY", you could probably just split it at the whitespace:

```
string name = "S101 Peter".Split(' ')[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way would be `"S101 Peter".Split(' ')[1]`

Answer (score 1):

You can also do .Split(' ')[1]

Answer (score 1):

```
string s = "S101 Peter";
string[] substrings = s.split(' ');
string result = substrings [1];
```